# sudoers file optional command arguments

Tags: linux, security, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to restrict `systemctl` command to allow sudoers to perform some modification commands (e.g. stop/stop/restart) on a specified unit (e.g. me.service), while allowing any number of `systemctl` options (e.g. --no-block/--force/--reverse/-f etc.)

If regexp was allowed, this is kind of what I want:

```
%group-one ALL=(root) /bin/systemctl ([-][-]*[[:alpha:]]+)* start me.service
```

But obviously I only have POSIX glob to work with.

I want to avoid typing out each and every permutation of `systemctl` options there is to replace that regexp. I am also open to using a script `mectl` that wraps the `systemctl` to do what I want.

There must be some good solutions to lock down some arguments of a command during `sudo` but not others. How would you solve it?

TIA

Comment: You may find a suitable answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/510244